# React JS: How to implement a popup window similar to gmail new message window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I need a 'pop window' with close and minimize functions like the one Gmail uses for new messages in my react js application.  Any idea how to do that?

This is a component that will stay visible even when I navigate around the application.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a library that is doing this?

Comment: Sure if there is a simple one

Comment: Lol, there is not a simple one, but you can use this. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dialogs/window/minimizing-fullscreen/
It's almost the same as the example that you described

Comment: Thanks.  So I should look into a customized dialog.  I may be able to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this one](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dialogs/window/minimizing-fullscreen/) if you want to install Kendo to you. If you dont then you can do something like this:

1. Create a modal(dialog) with header and body components. In header you will have three buttons: minimize, maximize and close. And the body of the modal will just be a CKEditor or anything you want. If you click minimize, you will be able to see only the header component and it will be placed in the desired place.